# Vector of rgb values to QImage

Tags: c++, qt, image-processing

Hi the context in which I need help is as follows. I construct a vector of rgb values (one rgb value is an UInt32) and i want to put them as fast as possible in a QImage preferably without setPixel as it is very slow. To take the first rgb value and put it at [0,0] in the image, next value at [0,1] and so on. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Try to use `scanLine()` method of `QImage`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#QImage-3) QImage constructor is what you need. The trick is only in choosing right [Format](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#Format-enum). I guess in your case it would be QImage::Format_RGB32.

So try:

```
std::vector<int32_t> pixels{/*init or fill-up your data*/};
int width = 42, height = 42; // your valid values here

// what you're interesting in
auto image(Qimage((uchar *)pixels.data(), width, height, QImage::Format_RGB32));
```

This approach is the fastest possible way - the pixels will not be copied, but original buffer will be used internally by QImage.

If you're going to render your image later with [QPainter::drawImage](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#drawImage), don't forget to pass Qt::NoFormatConversion as a flag - this will improve your app performance.

Comment: Works with `QVector` as well.

Comment: Any array or continues container will do.